# How to use parameters passed to a batch file in a for loop?

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, parameter-passing

Please consider the following...

This works:

```
for /f %%A in ('Dir /b *ipc10*.JPG') do copy %%A "%cd%\!sd!"
```

The goal from the cli> file.bat `*ipc9*` or `*ipc10*` or `*ipc6*` or etc.

... to get passed to the for command, instead of hard-coding each argument\parameter within the batch file.

I'm able to use `echo %1`, `echo %2`, etc. However `%1` nor `%%1`, will work as expected within that parenthesized command.

i.e.

```
for /f %%A in ('Dir /b %1 OR %2 .JPG') do copy %%A "%cd%\!sd!"
```

```
for /f %%A in ('Dir /b %%1 OR %%2 .JPG') do copy %%A "%cd%\!sd!"
```

... will not expand to the intended contents

Please advise.

Comment: Have you opened a Command Prompt window, typed `dir /?` and pressed the `[ENTER]` key? There is no `OR` option!

Comment: ... and the _set_ of files are `%1.JGP` for the first one, `%2.jpg` for the second one, etc. that is: `'Dir /b %1.JPG %2.JPG'`

Comment: @Compo, there is nothing in dir /? about this concern. Where are you reading from?

Comment: I'm not reading anything, I asked you to! Is there an `OR` option? ...Well then, if there is nothing showing an `OR` option, then my comment is unarguable. You decided you'd just include one, with nothing to justify it in the help information or any of the myriad of examples already on this site!

Comment: @Compo, I think you need assistance. I clearly was demonstrating what 'is' and 'is not' working. Then here comes 'Compo' to the rescue --sending the OP to a help file that does 'not' help or assist in any shape or form. On the other hand, Aacini did at least provide an example that works; thank you Aacini. At this point with the assistance from Aacini, I at least have an error free script; no thanks to Compo. All I need to find is a document that explains want Aacini provided.

Comment: Compo, I think you need assistance. I clearly was demonstrating what 'is' and 'is not' working. Then here comes 'Compo' to the rescue --sending the OP to a help file that does 'not' help or assist in any shape or form. On the other hand, @Aacini did at least provide an example that works; thank you Aacini. At this point with the assistance from Aacini, I at least have an error free script; no thanks to Compo. All I need to find is a document that explains want Aacini provided.

Comment: Only I know for sure why I asked you to read the help information, (although IMO it is clear in my opening comment). You were directed to it, @query-01, to verify that there was no such option as `OR`. As you cannot possibly know my thought process, it appears to me, as if you just wish to flex your argumentative muscles. Please however, be aware, when you do so, that there is site conduct guidance. If I was easily upset, or suffering from mental health issues, telling me I need assistance, would possibly fall on the wrong side of such guidance.